# Button opacity does not apply

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, opacity

So I am trying to make a button template. However, I cannot get background opacity to work, despite having implemented it exactly the same way as for the parent container (where it works). If I completely remove the background setter from the template, then it correctly inherits from the parent container, but then only the text of the button is clickable (and not the surroundings), so it appears that I am required to set the background for the button itself.

How do I make the background of the buttons identical the the back ground of the parent control, without losing the ability to click the entire button (and not just the text)?

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <!-- This is what I also want for my buttons-->
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.8" />
    </Grid.Background>

    <UniformGrid 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Columns="4"
        Width="800"
        Height="50">

        <UniformGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                <!-- And this is how I try to achieve it -->
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.8" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <Border.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Border.Style>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </UniformGrid.Resources>

        <Button 
            Content="{Binding ValuationButtonText}" 
            Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
            CommandParameter="valuation"
            Foreground="{Binding ValuationButtonForeground}" />

        <Button 
            Content="Opdater Leasing Core" 
            Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
            CommandParameter="leasingCore"
            Foreground="{Binding LeasingCoreButtonForeground}" />

        <Button 
            Content="Opdater Motorregister" 
            Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
            CommandParameter="motorregister"
            Foreground="{Binding MotorregisterButtonForeground}" />

        <Button
            Content="Behandles Manuelt"
            Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
            CommandParameter="manualProcessing"
            Foreground="{Binding ManualProcessingButtonForeground}" />

    </UniformGrid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution. It is rather silly, but it works.

You replace the `<Setter>` background properties with this:

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" Opacity="1" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

By having transparent background, the entire button becomes clickable, but the actual color (and opacity) of the button, is inherited from the parent container.